# How to open URL in new private window in Firefox?

Tags: linux, command-line, firefox

If I already have a private window, then the new `--private-window` URL will be opened in the same private window (but in a new tab). How can I change this behavior?

So, basically, I run this command:

```bash
firefox --private-window example.com
```

Then (the first) private window opens.

Then I want to do the same — open the URL in a new private window:

```bash
firefox --private-window example.com
```

But instead it opens in the *same* private window (just in new tab right beside the first one). Adding `--new-window` as a 1st option doesn't change it (and from docs it is not how you're supposed to use it anyway).
Now, how can I force the second URL to be opened in the *new* private window?

P.S. If I don't provide a URL to the command, then I will get what I wanted — a new, *empty* private window. Why it doesn't work *with* URL?

Comment: Change this behaviour, how - new window, not-private or same tab ????

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated my question.